# Interference - the shortest way from the point of constructive one to the point of destructive one

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference

So this is a problem from Polish maturity exam.

[image: 2 speakers]

The image shows 2 speakers (G1, G2) and point B. The wavelength of sound coming from both speakers is 0.155 m, and the wave coming from both speakers is in phase. So point B is where the constuctive interference appears (you can calculate this quite easily).

And the problem - "Draw an arrow in the direction of the shortest way possible from point B, where the sound intensity is high, to point A, where the sound intensity is low". Essentialy what they're asking is in which direction should we turn from point of constructive interference in order to, by going in a straight line, achieve point of destructive interference in the shortest way possible.

So any thoughts on how to calculate, solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the $1/r$ decay, the point source fields can be modeled as 
$$f_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r})=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{p}|}{\lambda}\right)$$
where $\mathbf{p}$ is the speaker location.

The field intensity from the two speakers then becomes
$$I(\mathbf{r})=\left|f_{\mathbf{p}_1}(\mathbf{r})+f_{\mathbf{p}_2}(\mathbf{r})\right|^2$$
and the direction of increase becomes
$$\nabla I(\mathbf{B})=\pmatrix{-1.01788\\-0.18508}$$
by inserting $\mathbf{p}_1=(0,0),\mathbf{p}_2=(1.7,0),\mathbf{B}=(0,4.52),\lambda=0.155$.

#### Picture

The intensity pattern looks like this when plotted from $x\in[-4,4],y\in[0,6]$:

[image]

This gives visual confirmation that the previous value of $\nabla I(\mathbf{B})$ was correct.

#### Mathematica Code

```
f[x_] := Exp[2 \[Pi] I Sqrt[x.x]/0.155];
{X1, X2, B, X} = {{0, 0}, {1.7, 0}, {0, 4.52}, {x, y}};
conjugate[expr_] := expr /. Complex[x_, y_] -> x - I y;
Chop[D[(f[X - X1] + f[X - X2]) conjugate[f[X - X1] + f[X - X2]], {X, 
    1}] /. Thread[X -> B]]
```